# My async is returning undefined on await call

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord.js bot and I've got a function that is supposed to loop in an array and get an object returned by Sequelize for each element. Each value is supposed to be put in a map and after that the map is returned. But it always return undefined.

```js
class top {
  async run (client, msg, args) {
    const member = msg.member

    let factionName = args[1]
    for (let index = 2; index < args.length; index++) {
      factionName += ' ' + args[index]
    }

    const embed = await topFaction(msg, member, factionName)

    msg.channel.send(embed)
  }
}

async function topFaction (msg, member, factionName) {
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(member.displayName)
    .setFooter(member.displayName + '#' + member.user.discriminator, member.user.avatarURL)

  const actualSeason = await SeasonManager.getActualSeason()
  if (!actualSeason) return embed.setDescription(`Aucun saison n'est en cours.`).setColor('RED')

  if (!factionName) return embed.setDescription(`Vous devez entrer le nom d'une faction.`).setColor('RED')

  const faction = await FactionManager.getFaction(factionName)
  if (faction) {
    const users = await faction.getUsers()
    if (users.length === 0) return embed.setDescription('La faction est vide.').setColor('RED')

    const xpMap = await getXPMap(users)
    console.log('xpMap - ' + xpMap) // Is undefined
    return embed.setDescription('Classement').setColor('BLUE')
  } else {
    return embed.setDescription(`La faction ${factionName} n'existe pas.`)
      .setColor('RED')
  }
}

async function getXPMap (users) {
  let xpMap = new Map()
  syncEach(users, async function (user, next) {
    const actualXP = await ExperienceManager.getActualExperiences(user)
    if (actualXP) xpMap.set(user.get('discordID'), actualXP.get('count'))
    next(null)
  },
  function (err) {
    if (err) logger.log('error', err)
    console.log(xpMap) // Not undefined
    return xpMap
  })
}
```

I except getXPMap() to return a filled map but I got undefined.

Comment: try to temporary switch to a .then structure so you can catch errors or put it all in a try catch and log the error

Comment: What is `syncEach`?

Comment: `getXPMap` doesn't have any return statements in it. Since it is an async function it returns a Promise, but since it has no return statements that Promise resolves with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: the standard approach is to also mark where the last spot is where it still has the correct value

Comment: @SLaks It's a package that create a synchroneous loop : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-each

Comment: @Paulpro Well there is a return in the callback of syncEach function, it's not enough ?

Comment: @nolat you dont even have a return in the standard callback you only have one in the error case both need to return a vlaue

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Can you edit my example ? I'm new to node.js and I don't really understand what you're explaining

Comment: No, that's not enough. That is a different function that is just lexically inside `getXPMap`. You need return statement directly in `getXPMap` for the Promise it returns to resolve with a useful value.

Comment: @Paulpro When I try to return xpMap outside of the syncEach function, it's empty.. How can I wait for the loop to finish before returning ?

Comment: I think it should be enough to return xMap before the last bracket and you might need an await before syncEach

Comment: unfortunately i dont know how exactly syncEAch works

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I tried that but it's not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since sincEach is kinda a weird function (I dont know it luckily the source code is pretty easy) I jsut wrapped it all inside a Promise to resolve on the callback

```js
async function getXPMap (users) {
 return new Promise((resolver)=>{
  let xpMap = new Map()
  syncEach(users, async function (user, next) {
    const actualXP = await ExperienceManager.getActualExperiences(user)
    if (actualXP) xpMap.set(user.get('discordID'), actualXP.get('count'))
    next(null)
  },
  function (err) {
    if (err) logger.log('error', err){
    console.log(xpMap) // Not undefined
    }
     resolver(xMap)
  })
 
 })
 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that when I can

Comment: oh I should probably tell you that using unmaintained packages in not recommended

Comment: Yeah but that's the only way I found to have à synchroneous loop ^^'

Comment: I will try to change it the each function of async package

Comment: btw I dont think its synchronous since you have async functions inside it cant be